# Why read.FCS from flowCore package combines the last 2 clusters of the clusterID column?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I wanted to know if any of you have had the same problem that I'm having with the read.FCS function of the flowCore Bioconductor package. I have some FCS files that I have clustered so the last column corresponds to the cluster ID. Whenever I try to read those files into R using read.FCS, the last two clusters are merged into one, meaning that the events of cluster X and X+1 are now all classified under cluster X. This ONLY happens with the last two clusters, disregarding how many clusters the file has. However, if I transform the FCS file into TXT file and read it into R it doesn't do that.

```
> # Reading txt file
> txt_df <- as.data.frame(read.csv(dir(pattern=".txt"), sep = '\t', skip = 1L))
> 
> # Reading fcs file
> fcs <- read.FCS(dir(pattern=".fcs"), transformation = FALSE)
> fcs_df <- as.data.frame(fcs@exprs)
> 
> # Unique values for cluster ID
> sort(unique(txt_df$FlowSOM_clusterIDs)) # for .txt file
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
> sort(unique(fcs_df$FlowSOM_clusterIDs)) # for .fcs file
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
> 
> # Count number of elements per cluster
> table(txt_df$FlowSOM_clusterIDs)

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18 
 109 1022 1457   96  253   54 2187  244 2371  402  147   12  375  476  576 1851   58   59 
> table(fcs_df$FlowSOM_clusterIDs)

   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17 
 109 1022 1457   96  253   54 2187  244 2371  402  147   12  375  476  576 1851  117
```

If I don't read the FCS as a data.frame it still does the same:

```
                               name                           desc   range    minRange maxRange
$P90             FlowSOM_clusterIDs                           <NA>      17  0.00000000       16
```

Any clue?